# How to disable find shortcut on devexpress web reports?

Tags: angular, devexpress

I have a project with web reports. On Report Viewer I have a list which contains all available reports. The user has the possibility of searching which reports wants to open. The problem is that if the report's name contains the letter f, the focus is changed from search bar to report's search engine.

[image]

On [their example](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos/WebSpecificFeatures/ReportDesigner), if you click on preview and then hit the f key, the focus goes to search engine.
So when the user types the f letter, it should be written on search bar and not be opened the report's search engine. How could I disable this f shortcut?

A snippet of what I have tried on the angular project:

```
import { ModifierKey, KeyCode } from "@devexpress/utils/lib/utils/key";

keyCode = KeyCode.Key_f // f key
    onContentReady(e) {
        if (!e.component._isLoaded) {
          e.component._isLoaded = true;
          let diagram = e.component;
         // delete diagram._diagramInstance.commandManager.shortcutsToCommand[65625]; //redo
         // delete diagram._diagramInstance.commandManager.shortcutsToCommand[65626]; //undo
          delete diagram._diagramInstance.commandManager.shortcutsToCommand[70]; //f
        // delete diagram._diagramInstance.keyCode;
        }
      }
```